# Bash command to add values of unique column values

Tags: bash, awk

I want to add values of unique column using bash command.

Input file:

```
Hello 3
World 5
Hello 3
```

Output file:

```
Hello 6
World 5
```

Comment: There are approximately half a million questions on this site that do this.  Did you try searching?

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{arr[$1]+=$2} END{for (i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' input.txt
```